# "Please upgrade your Subversion client" error

Tags: svn, maven

I do regular maven command:

```
mvn clean package
```

... but constantly get the same error:

```
svn: The path 'D:\Projects' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
```

There is my environment:

```
d:\Projects>svn --version
svn, version 1.7.8 (r1419691)
   compiled Dec 12 2012, 21:11:09

d:\Projects>mvn --version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 14:46:01-0430)
Java version: 1.6.0_30
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "amd64" Family: "windows"
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the version of your svn server?

Comment: Is maven calling the `svn.exe` in your `%PATH%`, or using its own  SVN library/client?

Comment: I have "C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin" in my %PATH% variable. How to check that maven use it and doesn't use built-in SVN library?

Comment: Run svn --version on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it by adding `svn-1.7` profile in `pom.xml`:

```
<profile>
    <id>svn-1.7</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```